# C# WPF - Switching between Grids

Tags: c#, wpf

i am almost new to C# with WPF. I have a small problem. Maybe the solution is very easy, but i don't see it right now. So i want to make different TABLES. I use Grids to make my own table. Now i want to switch between the tables at different states of my application, so that i make a grid invisible and the one i need visible. How do i implement several grid tables in XAML? For example i have a tabcontrol and in the tabitem i want to place more than one grids, but thats not possible. I tried using StackPanel for example but then i have a gap at the bottom of the grid. I need a way to define several grids and switch between them. Before C# i worked with MATLAB and i just put every table in a PANEL and switched them visible and invisible when i needed them. Is there no similar way in WPF?

Greetings

Comment: One solution would be to put multiple Grids on top of each other (e.g. inside a common parent Grid), and set their Visibility property.

Comment: that's a possible solution, but i probably will try using datatemplates :) thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In such cases, i would go with UserControls. One usercontrol for each grid type. A sample (not related to Grid in question) would be like the below.

```html
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DTGlobalAdminManager">
                <AC:UCGlobalAdmin DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static GVM:VMAdminConsole.Instance}, Path=ViewModelGlobalAdmin}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DTCompanyAdminProjects">
                <AC:UCCompanyAdmin DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static GVM:VMAdminConsole.Instance}, Path=ViewModelCompanyAdmin}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DTProjectAdminManager">
                <AC:UCProjectAdminManage DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static GVM:VMAdminConsole.Instance}, Path=ViewModelProjectAdmin}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DTGlobalAdminAssignCategories">
                <AC:UCGlobalAdminCategories DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static GVM:VMAdminConsole.Instance}, Path=ViewModelGlobalAdmin}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

You can set up a content control and different usercontrols (each containing different grid template). Then switch them using a Style Trigger.

Comment: If it is helpful, please accept the solution as answer.